# Use the epsilon-delta definition to show that $\lim_{x\to\sqrt2} \frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{x}+x) = \sqrt2$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$\lim_{x\to\sqrt2} \frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{x}+x) = \sqrt2$

by using the epsilon-delta method.

I have been trying so solve this for the last hour, but I'm completely stuck.

Help, anyone?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $\lim_{x\to\sqrt{2}}x=\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I can't resist making an observation that is quite inexcusable in the context of this homework question (and I agree with the now-deleted comment saying that it was quite an odd homework problem to have been set in the first place): if $a > 0$, and $f(x) = \frac12\left(\frac{a^2}{x} + x\right)$ for all $x > 0$, then $|f(x) - a| < |x - a|$ iff $x > \frac{a}{3}$. This immediately gives an $\epsilon,\delta$ proof (or rather an $\epsilon, \epsilon$ proof!) that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = a$. But I wouldn't hand it in! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.

Find $\delta_1$ such that $|\frac{2}{x} - \sqrt{2}| < \epsilon$ for any $x$ satisfying $|x-\sqrt{2}| < \delta_1$.

Find $\delta_2$ such that $|x - \sqrt{2}| < \epsilon$ for any $x$ satisfying $|x - \sqrt{2}| < \delta_2$.

Then let $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$.

> We then have $$|\frac{1}{2} (\frac{2}{x} + x) - \sqrt{2}| \le \frac{1}{2} |\frac{2}{x} - \sqrt{2}| + \frac{1}{2} |x - \sqrt{2}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$ for any $x$ satisfying $|x - \sqrt{2}| < \delta$.

---

Response to comment:

If $|x| \ge 1$, then
$$|\frac{2}{x} - \sqrt{2}|
= \sqrt{2} \left| \frac{\sqrt{2} - x}{x}\right|
\le \sqrt{2} |\sqrt{2} - x| < \sqrt{2} \delta_1.$$
So, choose $\delta_1 = \min\{\sqrt{2}-1, \epsilon/\sqrt{2}\}$.

(The $\sqrt{2}-1$ is to ensure $|\sqrt{2}-x|<\delta_1 \le \sqrt{2}-1 \implies |x| \ge 1$.)

Comment: Nice way to do this.

Comment: Ok, this is making more sense now. I get the yellow box when the prework is done first.
I get that $\delta_2$ will simply equal $\epsilon$, since those expressions are similar.
But how do you work out $\delta_1$?

Comment: @Sondr See my edit

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{x}+x) - \sqrt2
&=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2}{x}-2\sqrt{2}+x)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}}-\sqrt{x})^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\frac1{\sqrt{x}}(\sqrt{2}-x))^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2x}(\sqrt{2}-x)^2\\
\end{array}
$

This makes it clear
what happens as
$x \to \sqrt{2}$.